# Why admob ads are not displaying?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

I'm trying to place ads in my android app but facing one issue. 
The logcat is saying

```
Failed to connect to remote ad service.
Could not start the ad request service.
Failed to load ad: 0
```

activity_main.xml -

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_mainpg">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

java file - 
    `MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-9368742373801645~2595542217");`

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("3EF57886E34C0084")
            .build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I've tried running my app on emulator instead of real device but still ads are not loading. Everytime I get this error failed to load ad: 0

What mistake did I make in the implementation ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you add internet permission in you Manifest.xml ?

Comment: yes, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: did you add this MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "your AppID"); in your activity ?